# Enviar uma variavel jquery via ajax para o PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estou tentando enviar dados de uma tabela via Ajax para o PHP. 
Estou fazendo isso transformando a tabela em JSON e assim enviar por meio do Ajax para o PHP.
O scritp está desta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#converter-tabela').click( function(){
        //alert("chegou!");    
        var table = $('#tabela').tableToJSON();
        console.log(table);
        alert(JSON.stringify(table)); 
        // Você envia os dados para o PHP utilizando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            // Enviamos os dados da tabela para um script PHP
            url: 'teste.php'
            , data: { 'dados_tabela': table }
            , method: 'POST'
        }).then(function(result) {
        // No retorno, apenas confirmamos
            if (result.success) {
                alert('Enviado para o servidor com sucesso!');
            }
        }).fail(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

e no PHP estou só pedindo para mostrar na tela se ocorreu tudo bem:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

var_dump($_POST['dados_tabela']);
 print_r($_POST['dados_tabela']);?>
```

Só que no script só chega até o `alert(JSON.stringify(table));`
. A requisição do Ajax parece não estar funcionando. 
Estou usando esses links para o script do   : [Ajax](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js)

e [JSON](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@0.13.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79760/discussion-on-question-by-igor-nunes-enviar-uma-variavel-jquery-via-ajax-para-o)